# Treatment of Ordinal Predicting Variable

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, ordinal-data

I am trying to perform an regression analysis where the response variable is ordinal and the 15 out of the 16 predicting variables are also ordinal. Besides treating all these ordinal predictors as factors, is there any other option? What is the best way to treat these ordinal predictors? Thank you.

Comment: Ordinal predictors? You may try for example: A) Use the predictors as polynomial sets. B) Quantify ordinal into interval via CATREG (categorical regression). (_But_: are you really sure your variables must be treated as ordinal and not interval?)